# More than one form in one view. Spring web flow + displaytag + checkbox

Tags: spring-webflow, displaytag

I have a table, using display tag, in my application, that is using spring web flow. I would like to have a check box in each row, a button that allows me to select/uselect all and a button to execute a function. After clicking the button, the action will perform some database actions and the page should be render, so we can see these changes.

I don´t know which could be the best option, submitting the whole table

```
<form method="POST" (more params)>
    <display:table id="row">
          ....
   </display:table>
</form>
```

Or only the checkbox column. I this case I wouldn´t know how to implement it.

I have tryed two different approaches:
1. Using a simple input text, checkbox type. This is not possible, because when I submit the form, I need to set a path to another page.jsp (I am working with flows). Besides, I wouldn´t know how to send these values to java backend.

1. Using spring tags.
   In this case, the problem comes whith the class `conversationAction`

I found some [examples](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html), but allways using MVC and controller cases.

How could I implement this issue??

**EDIT**
I have found a kind of solution, but I faced a new problem...

**flow.xml**

```
 var name="model1" class="com.project.Model1"/>
 var name="model2" class="com.project.Model2"/>

view-state id="overview" model="formAggregation">
...
</view-state>
```

**page.jsp**

```
 form:form modelAttribute="formAggregation.model1" id="overviewForm">
...
/form:form>
...
 form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="formAggregation.model2">
    display:table id="row" name="displayTagValueList" requestURI="overview?_eventId=tableAction">

display:column title="">
            form:checkbox path="conversationIds" value="${row.threadId}"/>
        /display:column>

/display:table>
        input type="submit" name="_eventId_oneFunction" value="Send>>"/>
    /form:form>
```

**FormAggregation.java**

```
@Component("formAggregation")
public class FormAggregation {
   private Model1 model1;
   private Model2 model2;
//Getters and setters
```

I need this aggregator, because I need both models. I have tested it one by one and it is working as wished. Any idea about that??

Thanks!!

Comment: I don´t know why, my second piece of code is not shown:






<form:form method="POST" commandName="conversationAction">
    <display:table id="row">
        <display:column title="">
            <form:checkbox path="conversationsToWorkWith" value="threadId"/>
        </display:column>
    </display:table> </form:form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn´t find a solution to add two model in a view-state. So I made a workaround, adding the fields I needed to the model I was using, `com.project.Model1`. So the result is:

**page.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" id="tableForm" modelAttribute="model1">
     <display:table id="row">
           <display:column title="">
            <form:checkbox path="chosenIds" value="${row.id}"/>
          </display:column>
          <display:footer>
            <div class="tableFooter" >
                <input type="submit" name="_eventId_workIds" value="Send"/>
            </div>
        </display:footer>
      </display:table>
  </form:form>
```

**flow.xml**

```
<var name="model1" class="com.project.Model1"/>
...
<transition on="workIds" to="overview" validate="false">
            <evaluate expression="actionBean.workIds(model1.chosenIds)" />
        </transition>
```

**java class**

```
public void workIds(List<Long> ids) {
```

Hope it helps